# Syntevo SmartGit/Hg 6.0.1 not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, smartgit

I recently installed the new SmartGit client for Ubuntu using the .deb package offered on their site. However, upon attempting to run SmartGit nothing happened. So then I downloaded the .tar.gz package also on their site, unpacked it and attempted to run SmartGit but to no avail. There are no error messages displayed at all, even when I run the .sh file in the terminal. SmartGit 5 runs just fine and I have the jre correctly installed so I'm not sure what's causing SmartGit 6.0.1 to not work. Any help?

Comment: So when you start `bin/smartgit.sh` from terminal, nothing is output? What about `~./smartgit/6/log.txt` -- does it show any information?

Comment: What Java version you have installed? Did you set `SMARTGIT_JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I finally found an error message by messing with the SMARTGIT_JAVA_HOME variable and running it in the terminal. Apparently, I had a major.minor mismatch with java jre's. So I updated my jre, changed the SMARTGIT_JAVA_HOME variable accordingly and everything works fine now.

Comment: @sgtkode It'd be great if you created an answer with your problem's solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an error message by messing with the `SMARTGIT_JAVA_HOME` variable and running it in the terminal. Apparently, I had a major.minor mismatch (version mismatch) with java jre's. So I updated my jre, changed the `SMARTGIT_JAVA_HOME` variable accordingly and everything works fine now.